# What is the loop invariant of the given program

Tags: loops, proof, loop-invariant, hoare-logic

I don't know how to find a loop invariant. I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone find the loop invariant of the given program and explain your method please.

```
{n ≥ 0 ∧ i = 0}
while i < n − 1 loop
b[i] := a[i + 1];
i:=i + 1
end loop
{∀j.(0 ≤ j < n − 1 → b[j] = a[j + 1])}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `while i < n − 1 loop`
2. `b[i] := a[i + 1];`
3. `i := i + 1`
4. `end loop`

**Invariant:** Before step 2, `1 <= i + 1 < n` and for all `0 <= j <= i - 1` is `b[j] = a[j + 1]`.

The invariant is (trivially) true when `i = 0` (there is no `j` satisfying `0 <= j <= i - 1`). Moreover, if it is true for some `i`, it will remain true for `i + 1`, provided `i + 1 < n` (otherwise the loop is finished), because after 2 we also know that `b[i] = a[i + 1]`.